# Mysql stored procedure returns null only first time

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here's a table named `code`.

`p_code` column is a parent's code

[image]

And the stored procedure should return a set of records combined by `p_code` like this;

[image]

The **procedure works good except the first time**(after reconnecting MYSQL, it returns null!).  What's wrong with it?

Here's the stored procedure.

```
 BEGIN
 DECLARE _CODE bigint(20);
 DECLARE _P_CODE bigint(20);
 DECLARE _SORT bigint(20);
 DECLARE _pre_P_CODE bigint(20);
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @CODE = NULL;

 SET _P_CODE = @CODE;
 SET _CODE = '';
 SET _SORT = 0;
 SET _pre_P_CODE = '';



 IF @CODE IS NULL THEN
  RETURN NULL;
 END IF;

 LOOP

  SELECT CODE, P_CODE, SORT, CODE_NAME, CODE_LEVEL
  INTO @CODE, @P_CODE, @SORT, @CODE_NAME, @CODE_LEVEL
  FROM CODE
  WHERE LANGUAGE = @LANGUAGE
  AND P_CODE = _P_CODE
  AND SORT > _SORT
  ORDER BY SORT limit 1;

  IF @CODE IS NOT NULL OR _P_CODE = @start_with THEN
   SET @level = @level + 1;
   RETURN @CODE;
  END IF;

  SET @level := @level - 1;

  SELECT CODE, P_CODE, SORT
  INTO _CODE, _P_CODE, _SORT
  FROM CODE
  WHERE CODE = _P_CODE;
 END LOOP;

END
```

And the procedure called like this. This SQL will return the second picture above.

```
SELECT
    menu_connect_by_p_code() AS CODE, 
    @level as level, 
    @P_CODE as p_code, 
    @SORT as sort, 
    @CODE_NAME as CODE_NAME, 
    @CODE_LEVEL as CODE_LEVEL
FROM (
    SELECT
        @start_with := 6001,@LANGUAGE := 'en' ,
        @CODE := @start_with,
        @level := 0
) vars, code
WHERE @CODE IS NOT NULL
```

I don't get why it **returns null at the first time**. Something's wrong with the procedure or kind of bug of MYSQL?

------------------------------- edit ------------------------------------

RolandoMySQLDBA, rsanchez, I tried your option but stays the same. It returns multiple rows and some columns are null .

[image]

------------------------------- edit2 ------------------------------------

You can see here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa033/1

Comment: Can you edit this sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a672b  so we can try it out. Correct the schema according to what you have and we can see it run

Comment: You can see here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa033/1. The problem begins when I reconnect to mysql. And it seems there's no option like reconnect in sqlfiddle.

Comment: sqlfiddle seems reconnecting after a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

From [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html):

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and may change based on the elements contained within a given statement; in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between releases of the MySQL Server.

Therefore you may want to change:

```
SELECT
    @start_with := 6001,@LANGUAGE := 'en' ,
    @CODE := @start_with,
    @level := 0
```

by:

```
SELECT
    @start_with := 6001,@LANGUAGE := 'en' ,
    @CODE := 6001,
    @level := 0
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but it stays the same. Only first time it returns null values. Really weird

Comment: What is it exactly that it returns? No rows? One row with all null values? Multiple rows with all null values?

Comment: Multiple rows with all null values.

Comment: this is the reason why it returns null. The function call is in the SAME statement with "@level as level, ...", so it's not guranteed that function call will precede that part.

Answer (score 2):

I see the natural order of progression

Here is your query

```
SELECT
    menu_connect_by_p_code() AS CODE, 
    @level as level, 
    @P_CODE as p_code, 
    @SORT as sort, 
    @CODE_NAME as CODE_NAME, 
    @CODE_LEVEL as CODE_LEVEL
FROM (
    SELECT
        @start_with := 6001,@LANGUAGE := 'en' ,
        @CODE := @start_with,
        @level := 0
) vars, code
WHERE @CODE IS NOT NULL
```

The only way @CODE is NULL very early is if the Stored Procedure is getting evaluated first before the inner SELECT query is called.

Perhaps you could rearrange the order of the variable initialization

```
SET @start_with := 6001;
SET @LANGUAGE := 'en';
SET @CODE := @start_with;
SET @level := 0;
SELECT
    menu_connect_by_p_code() AS CODE, 
    @level as level, 
    @P_CODE as p_code, 
    @SORT as sort, 
    @CODE_NAME as CODE_NAME, 
    @CODE_LEVEL as CODE_LEVEL
FROM code
WHERE @CODE IS NOT NULL;
```

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-02-01 16:18 EDT

The problem lies in this part of the Stored Procedure:

```
IF @CODE IS NULL THEN
  RETURN NULL;
END IF;
```

Try commenting these lines out and see what happens !!!

Comment: Sorry, I mean "null" is multiple rows with null values. And it stays the same with your answer. I uploaded the result capture.

Comment: I just plugged my code in the same SQL Fiddle. My code works. No NULL results at all. Please try it out...

Comment: Keep doing "run SQL", it returns OK, null, OK, null, ... weird

Answer (score 1):

Firstly that's a function not a procedure.

Well I tried the fiddle - it seems to go null every alternate execution.

@CODE is NULL and hence your output's are null when the assignment happens after the function call. Which is probably what is happening.

If Rolando's way doesnt work then you can do this. Well this will add some time to your execution and is really more of a hack. This should work since now the @Code cannot go to null

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT
    menu_connect_by_p_code() AS CODE, 
    @level as level, 
    @P_CODE as p_code, 
    @SORT as sort, 
    @CODE_NAME as CODE_NAME, 
    @CODE_LEVEL as CODE_LEVEL
FROM (
    SELECT
        @start_with := 6001,
        @CODE := @start_with,
        @level := 0
) vars, code
WHERE @CODE IS NOT NULL) InnerQuery
```

Might be a really trivial issue but could use more investigation

Comment: @Deckard Did you give this a try ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact given in rsanchez answer, the function call is in the SAME statement with "@level as level, ...", so it's not guranteed that function call will precede that part.

Following statement may work:

```
    select
        CODE, 
        @level as level, 
        @P_CODE as p_code, 
        @SORT as sort, 
        @CODE_NAME as CODE_NAME, 
        @CODE_LEVEL as CODE_LEVEL
    from (
      SELECT
        menu_connect_by_p_code() AS CODE, 
       FROM (
        SELECT
            @start_with := 6001,@LANGUAGE := 'en' ,
            @CODE := @start_with,
            @level := 0
       ) vars, code
      WHERE @CODE IS NOT NULL
   ) a
```